# Assign File.readlines[n] to variable

Tags: ruby, io

I'm reading a text file which has instructions on each line. I want to assign the text on each line to it's own variable. When I do this, the value returned is nil but when I output the value of readlines[n] it is correct.

e.g.

```
# Using the variable (incorrect result)
puts current_zone_size
>
```

e.g.

```
# Using readlines after variable assignment (incorrect result)
current_zone_size = instructions.readlines[0]
instructions.readlines[0]
>
```

e.g.

```
# Using readlines (correct result)
instructions.readlines[0]
> 8 10
```

This is my code:

```
instructions = File.open("operator-input.txt", "r")

current_zone_size = instructions.readlines[0]
rover_init_location_orientation = instructions.readlines[1]
rover_movements = instructions.readlines[2]
```

This is the text in the file being read:

```
8 10
1 2 E
MMLMRMMRRMML
```

Edit:
Is the file being closed? Is this the reason I can't assign values from File.readlines[n] to variables if I'm not doing the variable assignment from within a block?

Also, the file will only ever have three lines which is why I'm not using a loop to read the lines.

Answer (score 1):

[`IO#readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-readlines) reads all the lines in the file. It should not come as a surprise that, in order to read all the lines in the file, it has to read the entire file.

So, where is the file pointer after you read the entire file? It is at the end of the file.

What happens if you call `IO#readlines` the second time, when the file pointer is still at the end of the file? It will start reading at the position of the file pointer, which means it will read an empty file.

Therefore, if you want to do it the way you are doing it, you need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file every time you call `IO#readlines`:

```rb
instructions = File.open('operator-input.txt', 'r')

current_zone_size = instructions.readlines[0]
instructions.pos = 0
rover_init_location_orientation = instructions.readlines[1]
instructions.pos = 0
rover_movements = instructions.readlines[2]
```

Note also that you are leaking resources: you never close the file, so it will only by closed at the earliest by Ruby when the `instructions` variable gets out of scope and the [`File`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html) instance gets garbage-collected, and at the latest by the OS automatically when your Ruby process exits, which may be a long time later. So, your code should rather be:

```rb
instructions = File.open('operator-input.txt', 'r')

current_zone_size = instructions.readlines[0]
instructions.pos = 0
rover_init_location_orientation = instructions.readlines[1]
instructions.pos = 0
rover_movements = instructions.readlines[2]
instructions.close
```

In general, it is much better to use the block form of [`File::open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-open), which closes the file handle automatically for you at the end of the block, and also ensures that this happens even in the case of complex control flow, errors, or exceptions:

```rb
File.open('operator-input.txt', 'r') do |instructions|
  current_zone_size = instructions.readlines[0]
  instructions.pos = 0
  rover_init_location_orientation = instructions.readlines[1]
  instructions.pos = 0
  rover_movements = instructions.readlines[2]
end
```

Note, however, that what you want to do is horribly inefficient: you read the *entire* file, then take the first line, throw the rest away. Then you read the *entire* file again, take the second line, throw the rest away. Then you read the *entire* file again, take the third line, throw the rest away.

It makes much more sense to read the entire file *once* and then take the lines you need. Something like this:

```rb
File.open('operator-input.txt', 'r') do |instructions|
  current_zone_size, rover_init_location_orientation, rover_movements = 
    instructions.readlines
end
```

However, in the case where all you do is open the file, read all lines, then immediately close it again, you should rather use the [`IO::readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-readlines) method instead of `IO#readlines`, since it does all three things for you in one call:

```rb
current_zone_size, rover_init_location_orientation, rover_movements = 
  File.readlines('operator-input.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reading all the lines at once, now I'm able to set each variable outside of a block. Like this:

```
instructions = File.readlines "operator-input.txt"

current_zone_size = instructions[0]
rover_init_location_orientation = instructions[1]
rover_movements = instructions[2]
```

e.g.

```
puts current_zone_size
> 8 10
```